# Ember JS: Remove record from hasMany relationship and update view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to delete a record from store and automatically update the view that lists the items, but so far I had no luck.

I tried `tweet.deleteRecord()` in the `delete` method of the controller but it seems it removes all "tweets" a user has, it doesn't update the view and when trying to access the user tweets again I get an error.

What is the proper way to delete a record from the store, update any relationships the record might have and also update the view?

Bellow is part of my code:

**Model**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    screenName: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    profileImage: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    followersCount: DS.attr('number'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    tweetsCount: DS.attr('number'),
    friendsCount: DS.attr('number'),
    tweets: DS.hasMany('App.Tweet')
});

App.Tweet = DS.Model.extend({
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    containsURL: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

**Controller**

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    delete: function(tweet) {
        // code to delete tweet both from
        // App.Tweet and App.User.Tweets relationship
        // and automagically update the view
    }
});
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    <h3>{{ controller.name }}</h3>
    <ul>
    {{#each tweet in tweets}}
        <li>
            {{ tweet.text }}
            -
            <a href="#" {{action "delete" tweet}}>Delete</a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Method named `delete` are you kidding? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `belongsTo` relationship inside your `App.Tweet` model. For example,

```
App.Tweet = DS.Model.extend({
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),
    containsURL: DS.attr('boolean'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
});
```

Now when you call `tweet.deleteRecord()`, the corresponding user model's `tweets` relationship  will also be updated. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/Y9hLf/).

Comment: Thank you! Including the relationship in both models solved my problem.